# writing to google FireBase from android app not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have written an ANDROID app for some truck drivers.  There are only about 3 of them. They never remember their username or PW.. so I thought I would just log the app in and not give them option to log out.
That part works.
However, 
I can write to the DB from my ANDROID app assuming these rules...
I can confirm that I am logged in... 
And these rules work as you would expect.  I can write children with no trouble.

```
{
  "rules": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true
    }
}
```

But if Change the rules… all my writes fail.  What am I doing wrong?
This is one of my experiments....
I am writing to children, any other things I could be doing wrong?

```
{
  "rules": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    }
}
```

children include "BIN", "BinScans", "MissionID"
any ideas on what I am doing wrong are very welcome.

Comment: Without seeing the minimal code required to reproduce the problem, it's impossible to say anything.

Comment: I'm going to update this post latter, but I created a new Android app, New Firebase project, reproduced everything that I did before, and it worked.  Trying to figure out what is different...   stay tune.

Answer (score 1):

The sample rules in the [QuickStart guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules) use `"auth != null"`.  Try this:

```
{
  "rules": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth != null"
    }
}
```